# JavaScript - Creating elements based on an array of object data

Tags: javascript

How can I generate an element and from just an array of object data?

Instead of this:

```
var element1 = document.createElement('div');
    element1.style.width = '100px';
    element1.style.height = '100px';
```

I want (something like) this:

```
element = [none, element1, element2, element3, etc];

element[1] = {name:'element1', type:'div', width:'100px', height:'100px'};

var (element[1].name) = document.createElement(element[1].type);
    (element[1].name).style.width = element[1].width;
    (element[1].name).style.height= element[1].height;
```

Comment: It isn't an assignment. I just want to know the easiest way to do something like this.

Comment: So loop........

Answer (score 1):

There's no native method for doing this (AFAIK), but you can try an improvised one, like

```
function ArrayToElements(array) {
  let elemList = {};
  for (let i of array) {
    let elem = document.createElement(i.type);
    for (let j in i.attr) {
      elem.setAttribute(j, i.attr[j]);
    }
    elemList[i.name] = elem;
  }
  return elemList;
}
```

This method supports all attributes, including `style`.
I've created a working example [here](https://replit.com/@Larnyx/test#script.js).

Comment: how does that set style.width????

Comment: @epascarello Just set the style attribute to "width 10px;", so that the `attr` object would look something like `{style: "width: 10px;"}`. Here, I've updated my example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const elementList = [
    { name: 'element1', type: 'div', width: '100px', height: '100px' },
    { name: 'element2', type: 'div', width: '100px', height: '100px' },
    { name: 'element1', type: 'div', width: '100px', height: '100px' }
]

const nodeList = elementList.map(el =>
    document
        .createRange()
        .createContextualFragment(
            `<${el.type} style="width: ${el.width}; height: ${el.height}">${el.name}</${el.type}>`
        )
);
```

You can read what `document.createRange().createContextualFragment()` does [here](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-html-stings-dom-nodes), but essentially you end up with an array of nodes which you can then append to another DOM element, or the body itself.

```js
nodeList.forEach(el => document.body.append(el));
```